# keep cursor point particular column of datagrid view always

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view like this:
[image]

i am working on windows application..here driver column i have to give driver id..then i click enter..so that time cursor is moving next row release button..
i dont want to move cursor next row button..after clicking enter i want to get my cursor to next row driver id column..
how i can  set tab order only on a particular column.

any help is very appreciable..

Comment: You can create your own custom class that derives `DataGridView` and implement the `ProcessDataGridViewKey` method. For more info + example see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdatagridviewkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: sir,,can you please give some more idea?

Comment: after creating custom class what code i have to write in ProcessDataGridViewKey event?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, currently, when you press enter it will move to the next row (same column). You would like it to act as pressing TAB? and skipping the button column?

Comment: you exactly correct..when i press enter i need to move cursor next row of of same column..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to create a custom class that derives from `DataGridView` and set the behavior of the ENTER key so that it will move along the row but skips the last column (the Button column as in OP case)

```
class MyCustomDGV : DataGridView
{
    private int currentCol = 0;
    private int currentRow = 0;

    // Store the current cell position.
    protected override void OnCellEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        currentCol = e.ColumnIndex;
        currentRow = e.RowIndex;

        base.OnCellEnter(e);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        // Extract the key code from the key value. 
        Keys key = (keyData & Keys.KeyCode);

        // Handle the ENTER key as if it were a RIGHT ARROW key.  
        if (key == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (currentCol >= this.ColumnCount - 2)
            {
                return this.ProcessEnterKey(keyData);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.ProcessRightKey(keyData);
            }

        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the ENTER key as if it were a RIGHT ARROW key.  
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (currentCol >= this.ColumnCount - 2)
            {
                return this.ProcessEnterKey(e.KeyData);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.ProcessRightKey(e.KeyData);
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (currentCol >= this.ColumnCount - 2)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                e.Handled = true;
                this.ProcessEnterKey(e.KeyData);
                return;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i after creating this class i dont want to write any code in my grid view page?

Comment: Just change the deceleration to `MyCustomDGV`. For example, your old `DataGridView` was declared: `this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();` it now become: `this.dataGridView1 = new MyCustomDGV();`

Comment: sir,,i written some code in my DGVall_CellEndEdit click event,,now that code is not working

Comment: Make sure your events are subscribed. If you renamed correctly there shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: i want to change every where my grid view name?

Comment: now i just give this.dataGridView1 = new MyCustomDGV() after loading the data grid view..

Comment: OK, as long as you have `this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DGVall_CellEndEdit);` it should work with your old code

Comment: i have to give this code in my form load event or CellEndiEdit Click event?

Comment: in the grid view form load event i given like this:  this.dataGridView1 = new MyCustomDGV()                              now my current data grid view not working.(not loading any data to data grid view)